# How exactly do you use the javascript dom event --- addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

```
<input type = "text" id = "Height">
<button type = "button" id = "Work!" disabled = "true"> Work! </button>
<script>
var Height = document.getElementById("Height");
var Button = document.getElementById("Work!");

Height.addEventListener("input",function() {
if(Height.value!= "") {
Button.disabled = false;
} else {
Button.disabled = false;
}
});
```

I don't understand why the button is never enabled when the user inputs a value into the input field. I've spent 2+ hours on this trying every possible combination. My salt levels are off the roof at the moment, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you are setting `Button.disabled` to `false` in both branches of the `if`?

Comment: That and in one of them, you have `Disabled` with a capital D

Comment: Which browser are you using? Its working fine for me in Chrome (after I change `Button.Disabled` to `Button.disabled` - with small `d`)

Comment: @torazaburo Nvm sir, my ignorance and frustration got the best of me, you were completely right. Both "false" were stopping the event listener from switching the state of the buttons to disabled

Answer (score 1):

button is enabled when the user inputs a value into the input field.

```
<script>
function toggleButton(ref,bttnID){
document.getElementById(bttnID).disabled= ((ref.value !== ref.defaultValue) ? false : true);
}
</script>
<form action="" method="post" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
<label>Height:</label>
<input type="text" name="height" onkeyup="toggleButton(this,'bttnsubmit');">
<input type="button" name="btnsubmit" value="Subscribe" disabled='disabled' id='bttnsubmit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I now see my problem. After changing the Disabled to disable and creating a true and false states instead of false and false states for the buttons. Ive come up with the following better code that should work perfectly as i wanted to.

```
<input type = "text" id = "Height">
<button type = "button" id = "Work!" disabled = "true"> Work! </button>
<script>
var Height = document.getElementById("Height");
var Button = document.getElementById("Work!");

Height.addEventListener("input",function() {
if(Height.length === 0 || Height.value == 0) {
Button.disabled = true;
} else {
Button.disabled = false;
}
});
```

Comment: Instead of answering your own question with what amounts to pointing out a typo, it would be better to delete your question.